# Returning all points within a polygon

Tags: geojson, point-in-polygon

I've been trying to figure out how to use ST_Contains to figure out what points are contained within a polygon.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT "userId", "firstName", "lastName", "phoneNumber", "name", ST_AsGeoJSON("location")::json AS "location", "email" FROM "user_addresses"
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "user_addresses"."userId"
WHERE active AND (
ST_Contains("location", 
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[
        [
            [-93.55697, 45.09112],
            [-93.50679, 45.04322],
            [-93.48239, 45.06378],
            [-93.50238, 45.08242],
            [-93.55697, 45.09112],
        ]
            ]}')
    )
);
```

The query is currently not returning any data,

"location" is stored as `SRID=4326;POINT(-93.501611 45.063169)`

I'm a bit of a beginner to all of this.

Comment: Read for example https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html carefully and change the order of your geometries in ST_Contains.

Comment: Otherwise try with [`ST_Within()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html)